# how to check what certificates being sent to iis

Tags: wcf, authentication, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

We have a WCF server , Our client claim they can not get pass our IIS 8.5 authentication using the client certificate we provided.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding" sendTimeout="00:01:30">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

From our IIS log , we can see the client get ether `403 13 2148081683` or `403 16 2148204809`

I am certain that the cert we ask the client to use is good, because we bought it from a globally trusted CA and we tested it on our end and it work perfectly fine.

And we do send them the full .pfx cert including the private key and gave them the password as well.

I am suspect that they are either not using the cert we provided or they do not install the cert properly.

The reason I suspect they are not using the correct cert is because they get `403 13 2148081683` , our fire wall only open for our cert CA to download the Certificate Revocation List(CRL), if they pass a wrong cert , they will get 403.13 because we are not be able to download the CRL.

The reason I suspect they are not install the cert properly is because they get `403.16`.

**So My question is :**

Is there any way from IIS I can check what cert they send us and do they have properly installed the cert ?

Comment: Did you try this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: On their end, they need to pick which cert they send, via configuration.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client  Ask to get a copy of their config file to confirm that they set up their config properly.

Comment: @Zergatul Good suggestion, i definitely going to give it a try to see what the report gonna looks like on cert authentication.

Comment: @tgolisch First, the client might not even use config file to set up the cert, they may use whatever tool they choose like SoapUI. Second  I don't believe whatever they send to me, clearly they are not aware where goes wrong, even they send me a correct config file , there are still many other place can go wrong, like they install the cert without private key. I have to prove on our end that what they send is correct.

Comment: Capture SSL/TLS handshakes should reveal what certificate is used when such errors happen.

Comment: @LexLi How to Capture SSL/TLS handshakes purely from IIS ? The IIS is hosted on an external managed server which i don't have full control.

Comment: Then ask your client to capture. They can follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2012/03/30/capture-a-network-trace-without-installing-anything-capture-a-network-trace-of-a-reboot/ but I think you probably should extract the steps and teach them how to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Found an article today..
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088156/Connecting-External-Systems-using-HTTPS-and-Certif

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\IP:Port]
"DefaultSslCertCheckMode"=dword:00000001